# Are Yoshis citizens of the Mushroom Kingdom?

Tags: video-games, super-mario-brothers

Things can be confusing for a bizarre fictional world in which animals can be first-class citizens. Whenever I've encountered Yoshis (I don't know whether I interact with the same Yoshi everywhere or an entire species of them is in existence), Mario rides them (*Yoshi's Island*, *Super Mario World*).

Are Yoshis animals (-equivalent) in the Mushroom Kingdom? Or, are they first-class citizens?

Comment: We've seen multiple Yoshis at once in many games, as well as Yoshis that vary in color, appearance, and personality, and some are even named characters. They are definitely a species with many members.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yoshis were first introduced in *Super Mario World*. In that game, they are residents of Dinosaur Land - specifically, they live on Yoshi's Island, a part of Dinosaur Land (apparently the species is named after the island). Mario and Luigi are on holiday there after the events of *Super Mario Brothers 3*, when they find a strange egg, which hatches into Yoshi. He explains that the Koopas had sealed him and his friends into these giant eggs, and Mario and Luigi agree to travel with him to rescue his friends (and hunt for Princess Toadstool, who has been kidnapped). They are not Mushroom Kingdom citizens, then, as they live in their own separate land; but they are certainly more than animals (they can talk, build houses, etc.).

> [image: Screenshot of the "Story" of Super Mario Brothers 3 quoted below; it also shows Mario flying on Yoshi, Luigi waving and Princess Toadstool]
>
> After saving the Mushroom Kingdom from Bowser and the rest of the Koopas in Super Mario 3, Mario and Luigi needed to recuperate from their adventures. Together they agreed that the best place to vacation was a magical place called Dinosaur Land.
>
> But while Mario and Luigi reclined on the beach for a relaxing nap, Princess Toadstool disappeared, apparently seized by evil forces. After searching for hours for their missing friend, Mario and Luigi came upon an enormous egg in the forest.
>
> Suddenly the egg hatched, and out popped a young dinosaur named YOSHI, who proceeded to tell Mario and Luigi a sad tale of how his dinosaur pals were sealed in similar eggs by a group of monstrous turtles.
>
> "Monstrous turtles!," exclaimed Luigi. Bowser and his bunch have returned!" Mario slowly nodded his head in agreement and, along with Luigi and Yoshi, set off across Dinosaur Land to find the Princess ad to free Yoshi's friends. As they began their journey, Yoshi handed Mario a beautiful cape. "This may help you," Yoshi said. "Some say it has magical powers."
>
> With a little luck (and help from a magic cape), our hearty crew can defeat the sever worlds of Bowser's Krazy Koopa Kritters. Many locations are well-hidden so explore everywhere and try everything. Not all locations have to be explored to rescue the dinosaurs and save Princess toadstool, but there are many "starry" treasures to be found in far-reaching places. You'll need to search all areas to find out what kinds of treasures are there... in Super Mario World.

Comment: You say "apparently the species is named after the island". Is there evidence that this is the case, and not the inverse?

Comment: What about Yoshis that move to the Mushroom Kingdom and their descendants? Are they barred from citizenship due to institutionalized racism?

Comment: @Jetpack I would say that's quite likely. Even the gallant Mario is not above killing them off if it will give him a boost in his quest.

Comment: "gallant" seems an odd adjective for a mushroom addict that commit genocide for a girl. He should be judged in an international court for all his crimes.

Comment: @Logarr: Mario is not responsible for what you make Mario do :)

Comment: @Flater Marios don't stomp Goombas. Gamers stomp Goombas.

Comment: @ElizaWilson Yes, this is mentioned specifically later on in the manual - "By the way, Yoshi was first discovered on Yoshi's Island, that's how he got his name." (Page 19, Super Mario World Instruction Booklet). Of course, that's the English manual - I'm not sure what the Japanese one says, since in Japanese it's called Yo'ster Island (a play off Easter Island).